# How to block SMSs from certain "named" senders?

Tags: sms-blocking, spam

There are many tools around to block unwanted SMSs. Samsung Galaxy S3's Jelly Bean offers a native call&sms blocker too.

But some senders are not phone numbers, they are alphanumeric strings.
I would like to get rid of this spammer, and my provider says they can't block SMSs on their own.

Currently, I wouldn't like to block "anonymous" SMS because I haven't yet received spam (better say mobbing) from undisclosed/private senders.

I've tried to use [Root Call Blocker Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.rootcallblocker.pro), but it doesn't seem to support named senders too.

## Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

[image: SMS screenshot]